# Is it possible to introduce a Gandhi tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently asked a [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91780/a-foucalt-ian-analysis-of-gandhis-satyagraha) and realized there is a Foucault tag but no Gandhi tag. Is it possible to introduce a Gandhi tag?

Comment: Yes!  It is *possible*. But is it wise?  All right, more seriously, there are 35 mentions of Gandhi on the site, but not all of them are questions.

Comment: It looks like there are tags for a number of other philosophers as well: Kant, Aristotle, Plato, Marx, Hume, Socrates, etc.